# React: how to separate one route from CSSTransition?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-transition-group

I have a few routes under a transition group like this:

```
<TransitionGroup>
    <CSSTransition key={location.key} mountOnEnter={true} unMountOnExit={true} timeout={800} classNames="fade-up-down">
        <Switch location={location}>
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route exact path="/artists" component={Artists} />
            <Route path="/artworks/:slug" component={Artwork} />
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
    </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
```

I want to take the `<Route path="/artworks/:slug" component={Artwork} />` out of that group and apply a different transition for that. Would greatly appreciate if someone points me to the right direction!